# Determining the properties of solutions of a first order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following is a general solution of a first order linear ODE
$$y(t)=(\frac{10}{t+C})^{10}$$

$$y(t)=(t+C)e^{sin(t)}$$

$$y(t)=\frac{23Ce^{0.1t}}{23+C(e^{0.1t}-1)}$$

What i tried

I know it cannot be the second equation since if i differentiate it there will be a $sint$ hence it cannot be linear. Between the first and the third equation, I believe it is the first one because if i differentiate th first equation somehow it gives me a linear equation. Im not too sure how to see it though. Could anyone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Since a first order linear ODE, $y+p(t)y=q(t)$, has the general solution $y(t)$ given by $$y(t)e^{\int p(t)dt}=\int q(t)e^{\int p(t)dt}dt$$

It follows $y(t)=(t+C)e^{\sin t}$ is the general solution of $$\frac{dy}{dt}-(\cos t)y=e^{\sin t}$$